# Keeping multiple counter integers and their respective object in a single ordered data structure?

Tags: java, variables, count, counter

So im trying to keep track of how many times each key on the keyboard is pressed, so I need something like a TreeMap that is ordered by variables. Anyone know a good data structure that takes care of this?

Comment: Seems similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java).

Comment: What do you mean ordered? You need to specify what kind of order you're talking about here.

Comment: Lets say its a TreeMap<Integer,Integer>. It would be ordered from highest to lowest by the value, instead of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `TreeMap`? It has the ability to order its elements using a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can define a class that implements `Comparator` which will determine which of two `char`'s is "greater" than the other, thereby providing a means of ordering. I think `String` has a method for doing just this; your `Comparator` will just need to convert the `char`'s into `String`'s and then return the value of `String.compare`.

Comment: I tried this, but i get a NullPointerException when my TreeSet gets two objects to compare

Comment: I figured out why, Java doesn't pass TreeMaps by reference so the map inside my comparator isn't the same as the one in my main code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make an int array where key value corresponds to array index?  As long as you aren't supporting beyond e.g. standard ASCII, this should be reasonable.

Comment: That wouldn't be ordered. I'd probably make a method for that but i wanted to see if there was an easier way first

Comment: Lets say its a TreeMap<Integer,Integer>. It would be ordered from highest to lowest by the value, instead of the key.

Comment: No it wouldn't, it'd be ordered by the key.